# Banshee: how to customize folder hierarchy?

Tags: banshee, cd-ripping

Banshee is a nice music player and CD ripper. In *Edit → Preferences → Source Specific → Source: Music* I can configure the folder hierarchy. This folder hierarchy will be used when I rip a new CD.

[image: Folder hierarchy options]

My pet peeve is that I just have these limited options. I've been ripping my CDs for 20 years as `%Year% - %Album Artist%`. This way, when I list a directory, the artists albums are chronologically ordered, allowing me to see their career evolution.

**Is there a hidden setting that allow me to create new options for Banshee Folder Hierarchy?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ops! Asking for a hidden setting, I've remembered about the existence of gconf-editor. So:

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
gconf-editor
```

And changed the settings below:

[image: gconf-editor]

Comment: Reply to me when you accept your answer and I will up vote. Thanks.